# Is There a Symbol for an Inrush Current Limiter?

Tags: resistors, schematics, current-limiting, symbol, inrush-current

Is there a schematic symbol for an inrush current limiter, or is a resistor used instead?

Comment: I might be inclined to use a constant current source symbol privately, but I'm not sure that would be understood or approved of generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICLs are generally NTC thermistors, so use the thermistor symbol, as follows (there are other thermistor symbols, this one follows the European conventions):

[image: thermistor symbol (Euro style)]